# Turn on bluetooth module manually

Tags: windows-8, drivers, bluetooth

I own Lenovo Y570 laptop and it has bluetooth module. I saw a transmit module name QDS-BRCM1043 in my laptop (a label at the back). When I bought it, my OS is windows 7. Bluetooth used to worked couple of time. Now I upgrade to windows 8 and poof... my bluetooth was gone. I've install all driver. But cannot install bluetooth driver cause it always tell "Bluetooth device was not found". My laptop only have 1 switch  for both wifi and bluetooth. So my question; Is there a way to turn on bluetooth by code or bios (I found no option in BIOS settings).

FIY:

- There are no settings in 'Control Panel' for bluetooth.
- There are no drivers in 'Device Manager' for bluetooth.

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing Lenovo Energy Management for Window 7 (not 8). It will tell that not fully compatible, just ignore it. Then you can turn on your bluetooth device with that utilities.

If you have no problem with it, so far I recommend use it.

But if you have problems, you still can install it (upgrade it). But there is one problem after that, how to turn off your bluetooth?

#### You have 2 options:

1. You can turn it off by disable it. You can right click on your network icon (notification area) and choose "open network and sharing center". Then choose "change adapter setting". And you can see "bluetooth network connection". Just disable it. Same way to enable it.
2. Use software from broadcom. Link: [Bluetooth Broadcom](http://www.broadcom.com/support/bluetooth/update.php). After finish install, you can turn off your bluetooth by choose: Start → Turn wireless communication on or off.

Comment: Link dead: "Windows drivers for Broadcom Bluetooth devices are no longer posted here".